# How to detect which of the two virtual hosts is being used in python and flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a website developed in flask running on an  apache2 server that responds on port 80 to two URLs

Url-1  http://www.example.com

Url-2  http://oer.example.com

I want to detect which of the two urls the user is coming in from and adjust what the server does and store the variable in a config variable

```
app.config['SITE'] = 'OER'
```

or

```
app.config['SITE'] =  'WWW'
```

Looking around on the internet I can find lots of examples using urllib2 the issue is that you need to pass it the url you want to slice and I cant find a way to pull that out as it may change between the two with each request.

I could fork the code and put up two different versions but that's as ugly as a box of frogs.

Thoughts welcome.

Comment: Why are you changing global app config on a per-request basis?

Comment: Its the same site only one version (oer.example.com) needs to put a filter on the records it pulls out of the mongo database (only oer records) while the other has a load of different cc educational material MOOCS, OER's etc  Seems a shame to have to do the whole code fork thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Flask `request` object (`from flask import request`) and one of the following *in your request handler*:

```
hostname = request.environ.get('HTTP_HOST', '')

url = urlparse(request.url)
hostname = url.netloc
```

This will get e.g. `oer.example.com` or `www.example.com`. If there is a port number that will be included too. Keep in mind that this ultimately comes from the client request so "bad" requests might have it set wrong, although hopefully apache wouldn't route those to your app.

Comment: I have tried this and using the flask server on port 5000 I get RuntimeError: working outside of request context?  with both the hostname and the urlparse solutions?

Comment: Do it in a request handler. You're not trying to put it in the app config are you?

Comment: er yes I want to set a global variable so that I can then use it across the app.

Comment: Oh. Your question was how to detect the host the user is requesting. That is only available in the context of a request. It sounds like what you actually want is 2 copies of the app running with different configuration in an environment variable or something.